# NativeScript importing iOS framework classes and downcast

Tags: nativescript

I have a custom Swift framework in a Cocoapod, wrapped in a NativeScript plugin. My NativeScript TypeScript code can do everything it needs to access classes and methods in the classes in the framework. That in itself was a lot of work to figure out all the nuances. Now I'm at the last part, which is to downcast a custom viewController in the framework from `UIViewController`. The following code is working, in that NativeScript actually loads my storyboard and controller:

```
var podBundle = NSBundle.bundleForClass(CustomViewController)

var bundleUrl = podBundle.URLForResourceWithExtension("MyFramework", "bundle")

var bundle = NSBundle.bundleWithURL(bundleUrl)

var storyboard = UIStoryboard.storyboardWithNameBundle("Main", bundle)

var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomViewControllerID")

console.log(viewController)
console.log(viewController instanceof CustomViewController)

application.ios.rootController.presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion(viewController, true, null)
```

The first `console.log` actually logs the full class, as in `MyFramework.CustomViewController`: hexcodehere

The second `console.log` logs true as well, meaning it knows the type of the viewController variable is indeed `CustomViewController`.

The problem is, I need to call a function in `CustomViewController`, so I need to downcast:

```
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomViewControllerID") as CustomViewController
```

But the compiler says "Cannot find name" to `CustomViewController`. If I try `MyFramework.CustomViewController`, it says "Cannot find name" to MyFramework. Notice `NSBundle.bundleForClass(CustomViewController)` works. So that means CustomViewController is known to the compiler.

If I import the plugin at the top of the file:

`import { CustomViewController } from "myplugin"`, it says "cannot find module" to myplugin. Mind you I can actually access all the classes in this plugin. So the plugin is definitely properly installed. It is installed from a local file path, not git.

It seems I'm missing something devilishly simple. But I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I'm happy to help others who want to use native iOS storyboard and Swift classes, etc.

Comment: Does `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomViewControllerID") ` return right controller already?

Comment: Yes it does. Then presentView with that controller loads up the right view and controller with all the right interactions. That's why it's so maddeningly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Attesting to the brain's ability to work on a problem in the background, it suddenly came to me. Since the runtime is aware of the type, all I have to do is to cast to "any" to get around the compiler issue:

var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomViewControllerID") as any

Then the compiler allows me to call whatever function on my CustomViewController viewcontroller instance without a complaint, and runtime is fine too. To be extra safe, wrap the calls to subclass methods in a if instanceof block.